# Create a new record in Google App Maker from spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-app-maker

I'd like to create a trigger in a spreadsheet, and write code, to add a record in app maker, and get back the id created by this record... is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes there is a way. You need to use [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to insert a record to your sql database.

Comment: Currently there is no API to interact with App Maker. You would either need to set up a trigger in your application or run the trigger in your spreadsheet and use the JCDB  service to connect to the same database that your AM application connects to.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger the spreadsheet change from appmaker as workaround ?

Comment: If you describe your circumstances a bit more maybe we can provide a solution. However, triggers in spreadsheets such as onEdit, onFormSubmit, etc. are specific to your document in spreadsheets, therefore it would be hard for App Maker to recognize a change in one of your spreadsheets for example.